# What is the use of Automatic update of date and time when i have to manually enter it?

Tags: date-and-time

**Step 1**-I have checked the Auto update date and time and Suppose I remove my battery and then place it due to some phone lag. On starting it shows the default date and time (factory set date,time) .

**Step 2**-As I had previously enabled the auto update of date and time the phone continues to show the factory date, time .

**Step 3**-I cannot change date, time because the option is blacked out. So for that I un-check the auto update date and time. Set it to today's date and time  and save it.
Upon saving the phone restarts.

If this is the case then what's the use of Automatic update of data and time when I have to manually enter the date and time for my region.

For what reason does the phone restart again?

Comment: If it's restarting when you set the date and time, there might be a bigger problem at the root of this. What happened exactly?

Comment: When you set the Date/Time to automatic, it should set, then maintain, the correct time and date by using a server (assuming you have internet access). It does not need to restart at that time.  When you remove the battery, does it default to automatic for date/time?  Also, a simple restart should be sufficient to fix problems; removing the battery is when it won't respond to any keys.

Comment: @Marty ,Dan plz check the update.I have simplified the process in steps

Comment: If you have an internet connection, then something is wrong with your phone; it should not work the way you say it is.  I think I would do a factory reset, unless you can confirm that this problem is somehow normal for the device you have. But if it is normal, then it is a broken design.

Comment: @mar can you explain what exactly does the automatic update do

Comment: The automatic time/date does exactly what you would expect - it sets and maintains the date and time no matter what time zone you are in, instead of your needing to set it.  Even non-smart phones could do that, and I have never needed to set the date and time for a phone that was provisioned, even without internet.  I'm not sure if smart phones need the internet or not, to be honest, but I mentioned that just in case (I'm assuming it's an Android phone).

Answer (score 2):

Your carrier should be able to provide the time and date even without a data connection. Most cell phone towers have a GPS receiver which uses the GPS data to sync it's clock, and forward this to the devices when they register to the network. Nowadays some towers might have a NTP sync instead of the GPS but the same principle still remains.

It seems to me that there is an error in saving the correct time and date on your device, which prevents the time from being synced from the carrier to your device. I'd suggest a factory reset (and/or reflash of you're on a custom ROM).

Comment: I am on the Stock ROM (Android 4.1.2) and I don't think doing a factory reset wouldd do any good because I am currently in SE Asia where most of the towers are a simple receiver and transmission only.

Comment: Still, the phone shouldn't restart when you set the time manually.